# How do I substitute a row in a two dimensional numpy array with a list of substitutions?

Tags: python, numpy

This is a VERY simplified example of a larger problem I'm working with.  How do I replace multiple rows in a two dimensional numpy array?  For example, I have an array...

```
main_list = array( [[ 0.  0.]
                    [ 0.  0.]
                    [ 0.  0.]
                    [ 0.  0.]
                    [ 0.  0.]
                    [ 0.  0.]
                    [ 0.  0.]
                    [ 0.  0.]
                    [ 0.  0.]
                    [ 0.  0.]])
```

I have a list of indexes...

```
indexes = array([3, 6, 2])
```

I have a list of substitutions that will always be the same length as the list of indexes.

```
substitutions = array( [[ 2.4  5.2]
                        [ 10.1  1.3]
                        [ 5.6  9.5]])
```

I want...

```
main_list = array( [[ 0.  0.]
                    [ 0.  0.]
                    [ 5.6  9.5]
                    [ 2.4  5.2]
                    [ 0.  0.]
                    [ 0.  0.]
                    [ 10.1  1.3]
                    [ 0.  0.]
                    [ 0.  0.]
                    [ 0.  0.]])
```

Right now I'm doing...

```
for i, ind in enumerate(indexes):
    main_list[ind] = substitutions[i]
```

Keeping in mind that this is a simple example, in the production version of what I'm doing the length of all these lists will be large.  Is there a faster way to do these substitutions?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
main_list[indexes,:] = substitutions
```

my attempt at timing says this is 3x faster than what you posted

```
In [51]: %%timeit
for i, ind in enumerate(indexes):
    main_list[ind] = substitutions[i]
   ....:
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.83 us per loop

In [52]: %timeit main_list[indexes,:] = substitutions
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.27 us per loop
```

Comment: Wow, so simple.  I was expecting something more complex.

Comment: numpy is great like that

Comment: TIL about tuple slicing :-) @Hammer, do you *need* the `,:` after indexes? because it seems to work without it as well...

Comment: @Menno it seems you don't.  That is interesting.  I like putting them there because it is a bit clearer to me what is happening.  I would imagine you would need them if you were trying to replace columns instead of rows.  Rows are the first index into the matrix so matrix[0] == matrix[0,:]